# Getting values out of a data.frame based on an index column in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I am trying to get the 'current' column to be the value in that row in the column contained in 'index'

If my data.frame Data looks like this:

```
         X1   X2  X3  X4  X5  X6  X7  X8  X9  X10  index current 
A        01   02  03  04  05  06  07  08  09  99   1      01     
B        0    1   2   3   4   5   6   7   99  NA   1      0      
C        00   10  11  12  13  14  15  16  17  99   5      13     
D        1    2   3   4   5   6   99  NA  NA  NA   2      2     
E        1    2   99  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA   3      99     
F        1    2   99  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA   1      1      
G        1    2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   99   1      1     
H        1    2   3   4   5   6   7   8   99  NA   1      1
```

I would like Data['C','current'] to be '13' because the index in Data['C','index'] = 5 so it would look for the value in Data['C', 5]

I manually made current have the values I want them to have, but I can't seem to figure out how it's done progrimatically

**Data**

```
Data <- structure(list(X1 = c("01", "0", "00", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1"), 
X2 = c("02", "1", "10", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2"), 
X3 = c("03", "2", "11", "3", "99", "99", "3", "3"), 
X4 = c("04", "3", "12", "4", NA, NA, "4", "4"), 
X5 = c("05", "4", "13", "5", NA, NA, "5", "5"), 
X6 = c("06", "5", "14", "6", NA, NA, "6", "6"), 
X7 = c("07", "6", "15", "99", NA, NA, "7", "7"), 
X8 = c("08", "7", "16", NA, NA, NA, "8", "8"), 
X9 = c("09", "99", "17", NA, NA, NA, "9", "99"), 
X10 = c("99", NA, "99", NA, NA, NA, "99", NA), 
index = c("1", "1", "5", "2", "3", "1", "1", "1"), 
current = c("01", "0", "13", "2", "99", "1", "1", "1")), 
.Names = c("X1", "X2", "X3", "X4", "X5", "X6", "X7", "X8", "X9", "X10", "index", "current"), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H"))
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try simple indexing

```
Data$current <- Data[cbind(1:nrow(Data), Data$index)]
```

Basically you are binding the rows with columns specified in `index` and extracting them from `Data`

**Data**

```
Data <- structure(list(X1 = c("01", "0", "00", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1"), 
X2 = c("02", "1", "10", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2"), 
X3 = c("03", "2", "11", "3", "99", "99", "3", "3"), 
X4 = c("04", "3", "12", "4", NA, NA, "4", "4"), 
X5 = c("05", "4", "13", "5", NA, NA, "5", "5"), 
X6 = c("06", "5", "14", "6", NA, NA, "6", "6"), 
X7 = c("07", "6", "15", "99", NA, NA, "7", "7"), 
X8 = c("08", "7", "16", NA, NA, NA, "8", "8"), 
X9 = c("09", "99", "17", NA, NA, NA, "9", "99"), 
X10 = c("99", NA, "99", NA, NA, NA, "99", NA), 
index = c("1", "1", "5", "2", "3", "1", "1", "1"), 
current = c("01", "0", "13", "2", "99", "1", "1", "1")), 
.Names = c("X1", "X2", "X3", "X4", "X5", "X6", "X7", "X8", "X9", "X10", "index", "current"), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c("inclass", "childage", "high_edu", "ref_race", "hisp_ref", "bls_urbn", "fam_type", "earncomp"))
```

---

**Edit:**

According to the newly provided data, it appears that `index` is of class `character` and thus you can't pass it as a column index, try this small fix

```
Data$current <- Data[cbind(1:nrow(Data), as.numeric(Data$index))]
```

Comment: I am getting an error: "Error in as.matrix(x)[i] : subscript out of bounds". If I understand correctly it looks like the cbind is giving me the row and column indexes, but then it's not using them correctly?

Comment: See my edit, I've added the data set you've provided. It works perfectly with your data.

Comment: What is the class of your data? Is it `matrix`? Does `Data[,"current"] <- Data[cbind(1:nrow(Data), Data[, "index"])]` works?

Comment: I get the same error. The class returns data.frame, but something seems different. I see the name 'Data' above the rest of the table when I output mine which doesn't happen when I use the Data you provided. Also my NA's are wrapped looking like <NA>. Do you know what might be different?

Comment: Please provide `dput(Data)`

Comment: Ok, I see what your error was. Your `index` is of class `character`. See my edit.

Comment: I had meant to edit the question, and edited your answer instead. I didn't know about dput that is really useful. Thanks!